# CakePHP Xml Library Save with line breaks and tabs

Tags: xml, cakephp

I'm trying to load Xml from a file using CakePHP's XML utility.

Is there a way when I convert it back to a string to save to a file that it can recreate line breaks and indentation of elements?

```
    $xml = Xml::build('../webroot/files/test.xml');

    $xmlData = Xml::toArray($xml);

    $xmlObject = Xml::fromArray($xmlData);
    $xmlString = $xmlObject->asXML();

    file_put_contents('../webroot/files/test2.xml', $xmlString);
```

The test2.xml is now saved as a single line.

Comment: Sure it is not just using ´\n´ linebreaks and you are opening it on windows with a normal un-smart text editor etc?.

Comment: That may explain linebreaks but I don't see any tab indentation either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didnt look at the source code.
Then you would have found out that there is a pretty option:
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Utility/Xml.php#L162

```
- `pretty` Returns formatted Xml when set to `true`. Defaults to `false`
```

Comment: Works great. $xmlObject = Xml::fromArray($xmlData); becomes $xmlObject = Xml::fromArray($xmlData, array('pretty' => true));